# Bookdown / Knitr / Kable Outputting Perfectly to HTML but No Table to PDF

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, bookdown, kable, kableextra

I am using the bookdown package to produce a large document with tables using the knitr::kable function. I can get the document to produce tables in HTML perfectly, but in PDF, the table contents just appear as a list of numbers. This is also true for the output to Word. The compiled LaTeX just appears to be a list of numbers as well.

This is also true of output from other packages like sjplot.

The same problem also appears when the [sample code from the bookdown book.](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/tables.html)

```
knitr::kable(
  list(
    head(iris[, 1:2], 3),
    head(mtcars[, 1:3], 5)
  ),
  caption = 'A Tale of Two Tables.', booktabs = TRUE
)
```

Produces the expected output in HTML:

[image: HTML Output]

But, produces the following in PDF:

[image]

The YAML header in index.rmd are:

```
#output ~~~~~~~~~~~ [see _output.yml] 
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: [bookdown::gitbook, bookdown::pdf_book, bookdown::word_document2, bookdown::html_document2]
documentclass: book
```

The output settings in the _output.yml are:

```
bookdown::pdf_book:
    keep_tex: true
    latex_engine: xelatex
    includes:
      in_header: tex/biblio.tex
    number_sections: yes
    pandoc_args: ["--top-level-division=chapter"]
```

Comment: What chunk options are you using?

Comment: You can make this problem appear even if you use the "new bookdown project" starter code. As I specified in my answer, it appears that simply loading the "kableExtra" package seemed to interfere with the PDF rendering of tables, even though the HTML rendering works just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the problem arises from some interaction with the kableExtra package

So, even if you specify (as I did in my sample code) the knitr namespace (**knitr::kable**), there is still some downstream interference if *kableExtra* is loaded. So, this ***will not work*** when rendering to PDF:

```
library(kableExtra, warn.conflicts = TRUE)
knitr::kable(head(iris, 20), caption = 'Here is a nice table!',  booktabs = TRUE)
```

While everything works for the HTML output, the rendering to PDF does not work for the tables and you just end up with a list of the table cell values (for both PDF and Word) - as shown in the image above.

To solve, remove any library statements

Then, ensure you unload the package:

```
detach("package:kableExtra", unload = TRUE)
```

And, finally, for me, I found that I needed to "Restart R and Clear All Outputs" or "Terminate R" from the R-Studio "Session" menu.